# Проблема с датой при передаче клиенту

Tags: javascript, node.js

Сейчас уже пол часа мучаюсь.
Есть сервер и клиент(браузер)
На сервере часовой пояс +3, в браузере у меня +2, я отправляю с сервера на клиент сообщение, в нем есть дата в utc полученая на сервере таким образом: `new Date().getTime() + (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)`
В браузере при приёме сообщения я извлекаю дату и делаю `alert(new Date(msg.date))` но время в этой дате уже на час меньше.
Почему?

Comment: Видимо либо в бразуере, либо на сервере daylight saving time не настроена, или расстроена...

Comment: опа, как бы `new Date().getTime()` равносильно `Date.now()` и оба возвращают время уже в UTC. не надо еще и часовую зону самому трогать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения времени в UTC не нужно к `(new Date()).getTime()` добавлять смещение часовой зоны. Т.к. оно уже будет в UTC. Соответственно, таймштамп сформированный через
`new Date().getTime()` или через `Date.now()` при использовании в конструкторе даты на клиенте вернет корректное время за исключением тех случаев, когда у клиента или на сервере неправильный часовой пояс. Для получение таймштампа лучше используйте 2й метод, нет смысла в инициализации целого объекта.

Comment: Я поначалу и делал просто getTime ибо везде написанно что в utc возвращает но после перевода в unixtime и передаче клиенту, а там перевода назад в милисекунды и отображении так `alert(new Date(date))` оно показывало не в utc, я подумал что причина в getTime который на самом деле не в utc дает время, а оказалось что причина в `new Date()` который время приводит к текущему часовому поясу, хотя об этом не где не написано. Data.how() - has no method

Answer (score 1):

Используйте на сервере и при пересылке, и работе время unixtimе (***Date.now() / 1000***). Это время не зависит от локалей, часовых поясов и т.п. Оно едино как, например, для USA, так и для РФ. И уже после, перед выводом для клиента, выводите его в виде человекоподобного и удобочитаемого времени в нужном формате(хотя, на мой взгляд, необходимость этого не так уж распространена). Что установлено у клиента (да и у Вас и на сервере) и как он настроил свои часы остается только догадываться. Но главное, что все свои расчеты Вы будете выполнять в одном и том же времени. А уже какой часовой пояс на сервере или у Вас лично не будет играть ни какой роли.

Comment: Перевёл на unix timestamp, всеровно время на час меньше

Comment: @Виталий, правильно. На локальной машине оно будет приводиться ко времени, установленному на этой же машине, с учетом часового пояса. Но само по себе оно неизменное. Т.е. у Вас есть некоторое 32-х битное число (например, 1457553721). Для меня это 23 часа (такой у меня часовой пояс). А для Вас, например, это 20 часов. [Так сколько часов оно показывает у Вас?](http://www.cy-pr.com/tools/time/) Мне кажется, Вы должны без проблем понять саму суть времени unixtime и локального времени каждого отдельного компьютера/пользователя.

Comment: Если следовать вашей логике то alert(new Date(какое-то время в unix timestamp * 1000)) должно не просто вывести время, а вывесте его с учетом моего часового пояся(+2) но у меня выводит с -1, да и вообще-то Date() не учитывает часовой пряс при передачи даты через аргумент

Comment: @Виталий Давайте проще. А какое время у Вас показывается по приведенной мной ссылке?

Comment: Нечего не показует, выбивает по таймауту по ссылке.

Comment: Строго говоря, дата выводится в текущем часовом поясе, т.е. если у Вас проблемы с отображением даты - надо проверять часовые пояса. Больше года пересылаю время между клиентом и сервером в таймштампе, ни разу не было с этим проблем

Comment: Возможно у Вас на час меньше потому, что Вы из-за очередного перевода часов просто поставили другой часовой пояс?